# How to redirect http and www and hide folders in the url and file extension?

Tags: apache, url, redirect

There is the following structure

```
/pages/yslugi.php

/ pages /

/
```

I want to make redirects with www and https, remove the file extension in the URL at the end, but should not open the path with the extension.
Example: https://site.ru/yslugi, but https://site.ru/yslugi.php should intersect or find and remove the pages folder from the URL.

It seems a simple task, I found solutions separately

```
RewriteCond% {DOCUMENT_ROOT} / pages / $ 1 -f
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Pages / $ 1 [L, QSA]

RewriteCond% {SERVER_PORT}! ^ 443 $
RewriteRule. * Https: //% {SERVER_NAME}% {REQUEST_URI} [R = 301, L]

RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ www.site.ru $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://site.ru/$1 [R = 301, L]
```

but all together it does not work, I did not find a solution for closing the paths with the extension (I found an option when both options work).

If someone has a solution to this issue, I will be grateful.

did not help but close

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[^?]+\.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$       [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.      [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(\.php|$) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your question, I do not know where to start.  Your structure does not make sense.  What is "/ pages /"?  Show us your exact directory structure.  Then `/ pages / $ 1 -f` does not make sense either.  Check your question, remove unnecessary spaces, show us exactly as it is on your server.

Comment: Pages is a folder with controllers. This is the whole structure. A request is made to the controller, then the view with the same name is connected. I do not have a Routs file. Building a path is formed in htaccess